# PHP PDO MSSQL ROW_NUMBER() error

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I'm using php pdo with SQL Server Native Client 11.0 as the driver.
Obiously I do cannot use LIMIT clause as it is proprietary and in trying to workarounf selecting ranges of rows I keep hitting issues.

My setup as follows :

```
$statement = "SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY USERS.name DESC) AS RowNum,  CASE.no, CASE.type, CASE.date,    CASE.ju, USERS.name, TBRLMF.rd_rl_description FROM dbo.CASE INNER JOIN dbo.USERS ON dbo.CASE.no = dbo.USERS.case_no INNER JOIN dbo.CMSTBRLMF ON dbo.USERS.relationship = dbo.TBRLMF.code ";

if($exact == 'checked'){
$exact = '=';
}else{
$exact = 'LIKE';
}
if($searchtype == 'users'){
$statement .= " WHERE USERS.name $exact '%$searchstring%'";
}else{
$statement .= " WHERE USERS.no $exac '%$searchstring%'";
}
$statement .= " AND RowNum BETWEEN :offset AND :max";

$statement  = $dbh->prepare($statement);
$statement->bindParam(':offset', $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->bindParam(':max', $max, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

and as long as I do not include the line of code :

```
$statement .= " AND RowNum BETWEEN :offset AND :max";
```

It works fine but gives me all the data.

When that line is included I recieve the following error :-

> caught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 207 [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'RowNum'. (SQLExecute[207] at ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_stmt.c:254)' in C:\pub\test\Classes\Core.php:44

I am at a loss and MSSQL is new to me.

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The predicate on that column can't be in a WHERE clause. (The predicates in the WHERE clause are evaluated when the rows are accessed; the value of that expression (analytic function) isn't available until after the rows are accessed.

You may be able to reference the column alias in a HAVING clause:

```
" HAVING RowNum BETWEEN ... ";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use COLUMN ALIAS (`RowNum` in your case) in WHERE clause. Rather change your query using derived table like below

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY USERS.name DESC) AS RowNum,  
CASE.no, 
CASE.type, 
CASE.date,    
CASE.ju, 
USERS.name, 
TBRLMF.rd_rl_description 
FROM dbo.CASE 
INNER JOIN dbo.USERS 
ON dbo.CASE.no = dbo.USERS.case_no 
INNER JOIN dbo.CMSTBRLMF 
ON dbo.USERS.relationship = dbo.TBRLMF.code 
WHERE USERS.name LIKE '%string%'
AND USERS.no LIKE '%string%'
) X 
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN 1 AND 10;
```

**EDIT:**

You can also use CTE (Common Table Expression) to get around this like below

Create the CTE

```
WITH NEWCTE AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY USERS.name DESC) AS RowNum,  
    CASE.no, 
    CASE.type, 
    CASE.date,    
    CASE.ju, 
    USERS.name, 
    TBRLMF.rd_rl_description 
    FROM dbo.CASE 
    INNER JOIN dbo.USERS 
    ON dbo.CASE.no = dbo.USERS.case_no 
    INNER JOIN dbo.CMSTBRLMF 
    ON dbo.USERS.relationship = dbo.TBRLMF.code 
    WHERE USERS.name LIKE '%searchstring%'
    AND USERS.no LIKE '%searchstring%'
)
```

Query the CTE

```
SELECT * 
FROM NEWCTE
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```

Comment: following that approach returns another pdo error 
 Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[07002]: COUNT field incorrect: 0 [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error (SQLExecute[0] at ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_stmt.c:254)' in C:\pub\test\Classes\Core.php:45

php45 is just where the pdo statement is executed

Comment: @BarryHamilton, I have no idea about PHP PDO; have answered this question solely cause the problem was with your query and if you run the posted query as is in SQL Server it will work perfectly. error you are getting probably PHP related. Anyways, try with the edited query once.

Comment: I tried just executing your code verbatim but mssql server rejected it.

Comment: @BarryHamilton, `rejected it` is not much clear. what error did you get exactly?

Comment: @BarryHamilton, OH MAN!! are you running the query as is? posted query is per your posted code. You should replace those `$searchstring` and `$exact` PHP variables while running in SQL Server. Anyways, have provided another option using CTE. check edited answer.

Comment: no I changed the parameter names to suit but used the aactual query exeact but for those changes in a pdo prep statement